# IGrouping<T,T> does not contain a definition of Leave

Tags: c#, linq

I am using `concat`. Following is my `relevant` code, it gives me Error in Linq `Select new` 1st Option `Leave`. I want to convert the SQL Query in Linq.

```
Select Code,Sum(DAYS) as DAYS,LEAVE  from 
(SELECT CODE,SUM(DAY) AS DAYS,LEAVE FROM LV1
WHERE DATE>='01-Jan-12' AND CODE='1' 
GROUP BY CODE,LEAVE
Union ALL
select CODE,SUM(DAYS1),Leave from LV2 WHERE
and code= '1' 
GROUP BY CODE,LEAVE) A 
Group by LEAVE,Code
```

Error in Code :-

```
var data = ctx.tblLV1.Where(m => m.Code == "1" && m.Date >= fromDate)
                     .GroupBy(m => m.Leave)
                     .Select(m => new
                            {      
                               Leave = m.Leave, 
                               Days = m.Sum(k => k.Days)
                             })
                      .Concat(
                      ctx.tblLV2.Where(m => m.Code == "1")
                                .GroupBy(m => m.Leave)
                                .Select(m => new
                                         {                        
                                             Leave = m.Leave,
                                             Days = m.Sum(k => k.Days1)
                                         }));

                        //var data = data.GroupBy(m=>m.Leave).
```

Comment: It should be not `Leave = m.Leave`, but `Leave = m.Key`

Comment: You also forgot a `,` twice

Answer (score 3):

When you do a [**GroupBy**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx) in LINQ, it returns `IEnumerable<IGrouping<T,T>>` where first T being the datatype of property you have specified for grouping your data know as `Key` and next T is the type of your list. So you can't fetch the property directly. You have to use `Key`:-

```
ctx.tblLV1.Where(m => m.Code == "1" && m.Date >= fromDate)
                     .GroupBy(m => m.Leave)
                     .Select(m => new
                            {      
                               Leave = m.Key, 
                               Days = m.Sum(k => k.Days)
                            })
```

Simialrly, you need to specify Key in the other query.